# Webscraping with Beautiful Soup and can not get serialized dates and other key value pairs from the application/json data

Tags: python, json, python-requests

I am webscraping customer reviews from this website for a project.
https://www.trustpilot.com/review/stockx.com 
I expect to scrape

Username, Date, Star Rating, Title, and Review Content.

I am able to get the text for the Username, title, and review content but to get the star rating in this script tag I need to access the JSON object for the "stars" key-value pair.

```
    <script data-initial-state="review-info" type="application/json">
    {"socialShareUrl":"https://www.trustpilot.com/reviews/5eb04df325e5d209b8e1bcb0","businessUnitId":"59ae88de0000ff0005aa7413","businessUnitDisplayName":"StockX","consumerId":"5eb04ddecc8cbb5d89fbab50","consumerName":"Morgan H","reviewId":"5eb04df325e5d209b8e1bcb0","stars":1}
    </script>
```

Then for the date, I need to get the "publishedDate" serialized date.

```
    <div class="review-content-header__dates">
        <script data-initial-state="review-dates" type="application/json">
        {"publishedDate":"2020-05-04T18:22:35Z","updatedDate":null,"reportedDate":null}
        </script>
        <review-dates :published-date="publishedDate" :reported-date="reportedDate" :updated- 
         date="updatedDate"></review-dates>
        </div>
```

What I have so far works except that I can't figure out how to pull the JSON object data and isolate it to create a df for analysis.

```
    import requests
    import json
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

    r = requests.get("https://www.trustpilot.com/review/stockx.com", headers={'User-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 
    (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:61.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/61.0'})
    source = r.json()
    source

    trust = BeautifulSoup(source, "html.parser")
    trust

    review = trust.find_all("div", {"class":"review-card"})
    review[0].find("p", {"class":"review-content__text"}).text.replace("\n","").replace("  ","")

    for item in review:

        try:
            print(item.find("div", {"class":"consumer-information__name"}).text)
        except:
            pass

        try:
            print(item.find("a", {"class":"link link--large link--dark"}).text)
        except:
            pass

        try:
            print(item.find("p", {"class":"review-content__text"}).text.replace("\n","").replace("  
            ",""))
        except:
            pass

    date = review[0].find("div", {"class":"review-content-header__dates"})
    date
```

The .json() method is giving me an error

---

JSONDecodeError                           Traceback (most recent call last)

```
    <ipython-input-102-7165ac9f6f1c> in <module>
          1 r = requests.get("https://www.trustpilot.com/review/stockx.com", headers={'User-agent': 
          'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:61.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/61.0'})
    ----> 2 source = r.json()
          3 source

    ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py in json(self, **kwargs)
        895                     # used.
        896                     pass
    --> 897         return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
        898 
        899     @property

    ~\Anaconda3\lib\json\__init__.py in loads(s, encoding, cls, object_hook, parse_float, parse_int, 
    parse_constant, object_pairs_hook, **kw)
        346             parse_int is None and parse_float is None and
        347             parse_constant is None and object_pairs_hook is None and not kw):
    --> 348         return _default_decoder.decode(s)
        349     if cls is None:
        350         cls = JSONDecoder

    ~\Anaconda3\lib\json\decoder.py in decode(self, s, _w)
        335 
        336         """
    --> 337         obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
        338         end = _w(s, end).end()
        339         if end != len(s):

    ~\Anaconda3\lib\json\decoder.py in raw_decode(self, s, idx)
        353             obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
        354         except StopIteration as err:
    --> 355             raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
        356         return obj, end

    JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

I think I am missing some parameters or a positional argument, but I haven't been able to find a solution through previous research.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated by Stephan your response does not come back in json format. Hence you need to transform the data into html using `BeautifulSoup` and the `response.text` that is returned. You then grab all of the tags you want (Below the code is using a css selector to grab all of the script tags that have the attribute equaling 'review-info'). You can then grab the inner script as a string, convert it to json/dict, and use it how you initially wanted to.

```
import requests
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get("https://www.trustpilot.com/review/stockx.com", headers={'User-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:61.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/61.0'})
html = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
review_info_array = html.select('script[data-initial-state="review-info"]')  # array of all review info scripts
info_dict = json.loads(review_info_array[0].string)  # using just one for simplicity
stars = info_dict['stars']
print(stars)
```

Answer (score 0):

The json() as you use it, tries to parse the response from your get request as json. This is usually useful, when the response is (only) in json format, which is not the case in this situation.

You will have to find that script tag, where the rating is included and then parse the content (or inner html) of this script tag. You can then use the json.loads() function to parse the json string. Like in the example below:

```
import json
inner_html = '{"socialShareUrl":"https://www.trustpilot.com/reviews/5eb04df325e5d209b8e1bcb0","businessUnitId":"59ae88de0000ff0005aa7413","businessUnitDisplayName":"StockX","consumerId":"5eb04ddecc8cbb5d89fbab50","consumerName":"Morgan H","reviewId":"5eb04df325e5d209b8e1bcb0","stars":1}'
star_rating = json.loads(inner_html)["stars"]
```